# $\frac{1}{x}$ series question help

Tags: calculus

Ok this is my first question so sorry if I've formatted it incorrectly.

I understand the shape of a $\frac1x$ graph. I have looked around and found an equation for the sum of the a series of values of the type  1/x that don't fully understand,someone please help explain.

$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n (-1+x)^{n}  $ when $|(1-x)|<1$

I want to find out, if it  converges, the sum of series:

$$ 1 -\frac{1}{(x-1)} +\frac{1}{(x-1)^2} -\frac{1}{(x-1)^3}+\frac{1}{(x-1)^4}- \dots  $$

when $|(1-x)| <1 $

Comment: is the edit correct?

Comment: Yes thank you .

Comment: The question as written makes no sense. $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{-1}$ is just the sum of infinitely many copies of $1/x$, that is, $x^{-1}+x^{-1}+x^{-1}+\cdots$. Also, the left side does not depend on $n$, which is a dummy variable, but the right side does. It's nonsense.

Comment: I know its the sum of an infinite series hence 1/x curve what I'm not understanding is what x and n are in terms of this equation

Comment: Is this better .

Comment: @DanielPrinsloo http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29

Comment: Let's start with this: what do you mean when you write, "the sum of the values for $1/x$"?

Comment: I know it is an infinite series that goes on forever what I mean is if I say between 1 and 100 what is the total which is what I'm assuming is what this series does

Comment: But your series would just give out $\frac {n}{x}$ since you're just asking for the summation of infinite copies of $\frac {1}{x}$ right?

Comment: No. What do you mean when you write, "the sum of the values for $1/x$"? Exactly what values are you summing?

Comment: If I have 1/1 that's one 1/2 is .5 etc and say I want to sum between 1 and 100 so between 1/1 and 1/100

Comment: OK, so now I think you want $\sum_{n=1}^{100}1/n=1+(1/2)+(1/3)+\cdots+(1/100)$. But your question has been edited to ask about $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^n\over(x-1)^n}$$ which is completely different. And you have accepted an answer about that infinite sum. So I still have no idea what you really want.

Comment: I gave you the hundred as an example of I wanted to understand how to sum the first n terms of this series

Comment: By "this series", do you mean $\sum(1/n)$, or do you mean $$\sum{(-1)^n\over(x-1)^n}$$

Comment: This series is for the sum of 1/x and I just didn't understand where the equation came from but now I do

Comment: But you haven't been given an equation for the sum, $\sum_n(1/n)$. You have been given a sum that adds up to $1/x$, which is a very different thing.

Comment: The question has been answered and someone else understood what I meant.

Comment: I suppose that as long as you are happy, that is what counts. I'm just worried that future visitors will see a question about $\sum(-1)^n(x-1)^{-n}$ with an answer about $\sum(-1)^n(1-x)^n$ and they won't understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u$ is a real number with $|u| < 1$, the geometric series formula asserts that
$$
\frac{1}{1 - u} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} u^{n} = 1 + u + u^{2} + \cdots.
\tag{1}
$$
Now,
$$
\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{1 - (1 - x)}
$$
by elementary algebra. The fraction on the right has the form (1) with $u = 1 - x = -(x - 1)$. Substituting, we find that if $|x - 1| < 1$, then
$$
\frac{1}{x}
  = \frac{1}{1 - (1 - x)}
  = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \bigl[-(1 - x)\bigr]^{n}
  = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} (1 - x)^{n}.
$$

Comment: So n is the term and x will be the x value?

Comment: Briefly, "yes". Normally, $n$ is called the "index of summation" and $x$ is "the variable", but whatever names are used, (i) a value of $n$ corresponds to the summand $(-1)^{n}(x - 1)^{n}$, and (ii) it's the same $x$ throughout (in $1/x$ and in the power series).